# AWS policy against compiling c code on EC2? No longer able to connect

Tags: postgresql, security, amazon-ec2

Does anyone know if AWS has a policy against compiling c code on EC2? I'm no longer able to connect to **any** EC2 instances after compiling postgresql 8.3 on my EC2 instance. I can't find anything prohibiting it online.

Has anyone had a similar experience? I've been able to connect without issue until I was compiling postgresql 8.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This issue was resolved by updating my security policy to allow for my **current** ip address. It changed earlier this morning and I didn't realize it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the AWS console to see if the machine is running still?

Depending on the instance type you may have used up all of the CPU credits for the instance.  If this is the case it will throttle back the CPU (on the small instances down to 10%) which can result in SSH not being able to respond (especially if the CPU is busy trying to do some intensive task such as compiling).

If you restart your machine from the console you should regain access.

I would recommend not compiling on an EC2 instance as it is going to eat into your CPU credits.  Either use packaged binaries or if you have to compile build a local VM on your machine to build the software and then copy this to the EC2 instance.

Comment: The instance is still running without issue. I wasn't aware of several potential issues that you raised. I was able to login to a new ec2 instance by updating my security policy to my **current** ip address. It had changed since earlier this morning.

Comment: These issues with CPU credits are only applicable for instances in the T2 family. This blanket statement of avoiding compiling on EC2 due to CPU credit usage is a bit misleading.